# Magento 2.2 install error: No images in Magento Admin after installation

Tags: magento2, error, installation, styles

I installed Magento v2.2.4 with sample data on my local using xampp.
I downloaded the source from magento.com/tech-resources/download as the user guide instructed.

After finishing the installation, I found this error, and couldn't solve it:

Icons and favicons don't appear and styles are broken, also requirejs doesn't work.

[image: Icons and favicons don't appear and styles broke, also requirejs doesn't work]

Please, help me.
I am new to Magento 2 and couldn't know how to fix it.

Comment: It seems that no images are shown...?! You could try to replace all occurrences of "Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink" in the file app/etc/di.xml
with "Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy"

Comment: Are you using XAMPP for Windows or for Linux?

Comment: I am using xampp for Windows.

Comment: Finally, I solved the problem. It really works well. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great - was it just the "Copy" instead of "Symlink" thing?

Comment: @dan i propose that you add an answer for proposed solution for best visibility

Comment: Yes, I only replaced "Symlink" with "Copy", and it worked like a magic. Thanks again for your help. And plz, help me a lot from now on. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no images are shown after the installation of Magento, replacing all occurrences of

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

in the file `app/etc/di.xml` with

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

... should help. It tells Magento that it should copy files instead of creating symlinks. This seems to be necessary on Windows machines, because Windows does not support symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

Log in to your server using SSH, then deploy the static content by applying this command on Magento root

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

more details about deploying the static content in this link

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Mr. Wisam. But sadly I don't know how to log in to my server using SSH. I installed magento on my local server using xampp. How can I do that?

Comment: In that case, you could run that command via command line in your local magento root directory.

Comment: Without logging in using SSH?

Comment: in your local machine you can login using "Command Prompt", then go to your magento root folder then you can do deploy static-content

Answer (score 0):

It is not an error. You have just installed Magento so the thing is that your static content is not generated properly. So to solve this issue run below commands in cmd:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
>
> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean